# How do I write an array of integers as a bytestream to the client in Nodejs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

> How do I write an array of integers as a bytestream to the client in Nodejs?

Suppose I've the array `[17, 256, 82]`.

I use the content-type `application/octet-stream`.

Now, I want to return a response containing the binary stream `0x00 0x11 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x52`, i.e., each integer is represented using two bytes in the stream.

How can I do this in Nodejs? I've been looking at `fs`, but can't find a way.

Attempt:

```
function intTo16BigEndianString(n) {
    var result = String.fromCharCode((n >> 8) & 0xFF);
    result += String.fromCharCode((n >> 0) & 0xFF);

    return result;
}

...

numbers = [23,256,19];

numbers = numbers.map(function(n) {
    return intTo16BigEndianString(n);
})
resp.write(numbers.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    return acc + curr;
}));
```

However, the result is not plain binary output. Weird bytes get intermixed. I guess this is because, `resp` is not meant to deal with binary?

Comment: what have you tried? where are you stuck?

Comment: I've converted the bytes integers into two-byte strings. Now I need to write them out.

Comment: you need to post some code so we can help

Comment: @Cruiser - I've added some code.

Comment: I think this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979800/send-byte-array-in-node-js-to-server#28087476

Comment: What should I replace the net.connect() call with?

Comment: i think you can just resp.pipe(stream)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `'binary'` enconding. By default the encoding is `'utf8'`, which may add additional bytes, when encoding your "binary" string.

```
numbers = numbers.map(function(n) {
    return utils.intTo16BigEndianString(n);
});

resp.write(numbers.reduce(function (acc, curr) {
    return acc + curr;
}), 'binary');
```